# Is there a way to clear contents of a CosmosDb container via DTUI command line

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I use DTUI from the commandline to load documents into CosmosDB from various sources. It would be handy if I could clear the contents of the collection prior to loading. Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to to clear the contents of a container using the data migration tool. In general what you could simply do

(i) set a [TTL of 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/time-to-live) on that particular Container, it might take some time depending on the size of the documents in that container

(ii) Another step is to to simply just to delete & recreate the container in the portal.